# how to execute doGet method of servlet by writing method post in form tag

Tags: servlets

The form calls the servlet `logout`.

```
<form name="fm1" method="post" action="logout">
```

This is the servlet code:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
                            throws ServletException, IOException {  
        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();          
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").include(request, response);


        HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
        session.invalidate();  

        out.print("You are successfully logged out!");  

        out.close();  
}  

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
          request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").include(request, response);

        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
        session.invalidate();  

        out.print("You are successfully logged out!");  

        out.close();
}
```

I am unable to understand how to get to the servlet to execute using `doGet` when I'm using `post` in my form. How will it be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call doGet(request, response) method in post method of servlet

Answer (score 0):

This probably is not an answer, and I am unable to comment, but why are you not using the `doPost` method?

Or change the method in the form to `get`?

Comment: In one of my interview I was asked how can we run the code written in doGet by specifying method="post" in form tag. if we write method="post" it will execute doPost but my interviewer wants me to answer how to run code written in doGet by specifying method="post" in form tag.